# How to open a new screen from another in Android/Java

Tags: android-layout

I am new to Android/Java and am trying to learn in order to create an app. I have done a lot of programming in Microsoft Access Visual Basic, but this is the first that I am doing in Java.

My (very basic) question is how to open a new screen from another?

All of the examples that I have found online either did not work when I tried them or crashed when I tried to customize them to open my own screen.

Also, all of the examples have so much extraneous stuff in them that I cannot figure out which parts are essential to just opening the next screen and what parts are doing other things.

In VB, to open one screen from another (using a button), you create a screen (form) and then add the following code to the onclick event of the button  docmd.openform("form1"). It is that simple.

What is the Android/Java version of this command?

What I am looking for is a barebones piece of code that opens another screen when a button is clicked on the first screen. The second screen would have nothing on it except a text field that says "this is the second screen." No buttons, returns, etc.

I know how to create the screens as layout.xml files. I just can't figure out how to display that second (or subsequent) screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a new activity from your current activity through an intent like this:

```
startActivity( new Intent(this, YourActivity.class) );
```

Comment: I put the following code in my main.xml file within the button description codes    android:onClick="startActivity( new Intent(this, screen2.class) );"  When I try to run it in the emulator, I get a Force Close when I click on the button. Of course, there is no hint of what is wrong. There were no error messages on the Eclipse editing screens.